# How to suppress OptionValidator of Commons CLI?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons-cli

I want to run

```java
java -jar application.jar -Dlog4j.configuration="path/to/log4j.xml"
```

application.jar runs with Commons CLI and needs external log4j.xml file.

When I run this command, I get the following exception:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: opt contains illegal character value '.'
    at org.apache.commons.cli.OptionValidator.validateOption(OptionValidator.java:73)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Option.<init>(Option.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Options.addOption(Options.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Options.addOption(Options.java:114)
```

because Dlog4j.configuration has '.'.
How can I skip this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by bringing the problematic parameter in front of -jar.

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:\C:path\to\log4j.xml -jar application.jar
```

Then Common CLI ignores it.
Once I tried this it failed and I abandoned but that was caused by the path without file protocol, `file:\`.

Still I don't know if Common CLI can skip the validation of options though.